# Why would a recruiter repeatedly avoid sending position requirements while setting up an interview?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, negotiation, position

To clarify, I have been working with a recruiter who has a position for me in the works, but so far he has been only talking about it.  That is, he went over the position requirements over the phone once, and I know things like the company name, and what they are looking for approximately.

There is a chance it may not be a great fit, but when I requested (a couple of times) for recruiter to send me the position requirements over email, he so far has neglected to do so.  I do not have a photographic-enough memory to recall all the requirements from the phone conversation and that's why I have been asking for the email.

My next step is to either call him out on that, or to just go to the recruiter's office and have the "interview" with recruiter and his account manager, as they have been trying to set that pre-interview with me for a bit now.  His purpose for this is also unclear to me, my only guess was that they want to get familiar with me, as a candidate, whatever that means.

My only guess is that he thinks I will withdraw my interest if I see position requirements.  Is there any other reason?

Answer (score 3):

## Because they don't want you to find the position

It's very easy to find the job yourself once the recruiter gives you the requirements.

Tell the recruiter that you need to see the list of requirements to match your skills, and explicitly state that lack of response immediately raises heavy suspicion of incompetence or foul play.

Comment: Foul play? This isn't a murder mystery. Recruiters are the gatekeepers to jobs. Insulting the recruiter isn't going to help this person. Patience, or the will to look elsewhere, certainly could.

Comment: But the OP already stated that he knows the company name and, presumably, job title, so he already has all the tools to find the position by himself.

Comment: @DarkHippo - the fact that the recruiter doesn't benefit from being sleezy won't stop him/her from being sleezy by force of habit, if they are one of the bad recruiters.

Answer (score 2):

More importantly, why are you considering chasing down this recruiter after he has neglected to send you the basic information you need to evaluate the role? Right now all you've had is a discussion. That's it. The issue may not be the recruiter, but the company contracting with the recruiter to fill the position.

Your request for a written job description is perfectly reasonable. If a recruiter cannot or will not provide that to you, stop chasing the recruiter and move on. Headhunters make their living by placing people in positions. It's in their interest to keep valuable and qualified candidates in the loop on available positions. If a recruiter isn't doing that, then either 1) the company is rethinking the role; 2) the recruiter is busy with other candidates for other positions; 3) the recruiter is busy with other candidates for THIS position; or 4) ... some other reason.

Let the recruiter contact you if they think you're a good fit. At this point the recruiter has your information and knows you're interested in the position. That's the best you can do. Showing up at this person's office, while possibly gratifying short-term, will only get you blacklisted as a difficult and demanding candidate. Why would a recruiter who thinks poorly of you want to recommend you to a company, at the cost of possibly not getting future headhunting contracts for placing such a difficult person?

Start talking to other recruiters. Leave this alone until you're contacted by the recruiter. Next!